# iam trying to install kendo ui library in angular and jhipster project but i have always the same errors

Tags: angular, jhipster

ng add  @progress/kendo-data-query
ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Package information loaded.

The package @progress/kendo-data-query@1.6.0 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
✔ Packages successfully installed.
Package "@progress/kendo-data-query" was found but does not support schematics.

i am using angular version 14.2.1 with nodejs version 16.17
i want to solve this error "was found but does not support schematics"???

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you use `npm install` instead of `npm add`? The `add` command only works if the library supports Angular Schematics.